# Reading from a CSV in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, csv, fs

### Problem

The `push()` function inside the `createReadStream` does not push my data to the array.

### The Code

```
let csv = require('csv-parser');

let people = [];

let final_array = [];

fs.createReadStream('people.csv')
      .pipe(csv())
      .on('data', (data) => {
        people.push(data)
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        console.log(people) //This prints out people fine
      })

console.log(people) //This returns empty array

people.forEach((names) => {
    console.log(people[names]); //absolutely no output
})
```

### The Output

```
[] //Output for console.log(people) outside the createReadStream

//Output for console.log  people inside the createReadStream
[
  { username: 'rezero' },
  { username: 'software' },
  { username: 'planets' },
  { username: 'darkseid' },
  { username: 'gintama' },
  { username: 'websines' },
  { username: 'digital' }
]
```

### Desired Output

I want only the usernames from the data to go into my final_array for further tasks.

```
final_array = ['rezero','software','planets','darkseid','gintama','websines','digital']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The csv-parsing will run asynchronously, which means `console.log(people)` (and the code after that) will run before the file was parsed completely.

You could wrap the parsing into a promise and await this promise (this still needs error handling, but should give you an idea):

```
(async () => {
    let peopleData = [];
    await new Promise(resolve => {
        fs.createReadStream('people.csv')
            .pipe(csv())
            .on('data', (data) => {
                peopleData.push(data)
            })
            .on('end', () => {
                resolve();
            })
    });
    const finalArray = peopleData.map(data => data.username);
    finalArray.forEach(name => {
      console.log(name);
    });
    
})();
```

Comment: Thank you, can you also help me loop the objects as shown in Desired Output?

Comment: Sure - I've updated the answer with a simple `.map()`, please check.